# Not able to make my cannon fire bullets in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In my game I can place cannons anywhere on the screen. I want my cannons to be able to fire bullets and the bullets should be reset after they travel 100 pixels. Given below is my cannon class, I'm still new to OOP so I require some help however I wasn't able to accomplish this task using lists either. Thank you for your help.

```
class Cannon():
    global cannon_list
    global bullet_list
    def __init__(self, x, y, track, old_x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.track = track
        self.old_x = old_x

    def spawnBullet(self):
        for j in bullet_list:
            self.old_x = self.x
            self.track = j[2]
            screen.blit(bullet, (j[0], j[1]))

    def moveBullet(self):
        if self.x <= self.track:
            self.x += 3

    def resetBullet(self):
        if self.x >= self.track:
            self.x = self.old_x

    def spawnCannon(self):
        for i in cannon_list:
            screen.blit(cannon, i)
```

Using the cannon class. this is under redrawGamewindow.

```
for j in bullet_list:
    cannonsAndBullets = Cannon(j[0], j[1], j[2], j[0])
    cannonsAndBullets.spawnCannon()
    cannonsAndBullets.spawnBullet()
    cannonsAndBullets.moveBullet()
    cannonsAndBullets.resetBullet()
```

Given below is what I have appended into `bullet_list` and `cannon_list`. x an y are the position of my player

```
            cannon_list.append([x,y])
            bullet_list.append([x,(y+25),100, x])
```

Edits in my class

```
class Cannon():
    global cannon_list
    global bullet_list
    def __init__(self, x, y, track, old_x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.track = track
        self.old_x = old_x

    def spawnBullet(self):
        # for j in bullet_list:
        # self.x, self.y, self.track, self.old_x = j
        screen.blit(bullet, (self.x, self.y))

    def moveBullet(self):
        # for j in bullet_list:
        # self.x, self.y, self.track, self.old_x = j
        if self.track <= 100:
            print(self.track)
            self.track += 3
            self.x += 3

    def resetBullet(self):
        # for j in bullet_list:
        # self.x, self.y, self.track, self.old_x = j
        if self.track >= 100:
            print(self.track)
            self.x = self.old_x

    def spawnCannon(self):
        for i in cannon_list:
            screen.blit(cannon, i)
```

Comment: What is the actual problem with the code?

Comment: @Kingsley The cannons and bullets are blitted onto the screen but the bullets don't move

Comment: If the bullets don't move, that suggests self.x is not less than self.track. Have you tried printing these values to ensure that this check is passing

Comment: @incarnadine  I just tried that and it seems to be printing however, the values are not getting updated. I realised that I was appending self.track as 100 and changed that to 0 but that means resetBullet isn't working. Also after changing the appended value to 0, it doesn't update the value ```self.track += 3```

Comment: I made some changes to my class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's discard everything and start from scratch and make use of pygame features like sprites and vector math.

We begin with a basic skeleton of a pygame game, a simple window:

```
import pygame

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Now, we want to place some Sprites. Let's create a `Sprite` class that represents the cannons, and let's place them with the mouse:

```
import pygame

class Cannon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('darkred'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

def main():

    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                Cannon(e.pos, all_sprites)


        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: enter code here]

Now we want the cannons to shoot bullets. To do that, we're making use of some OOP features, like polymorphism. Bullets and cannons are different types, but they provide the same interface: `update` and `draw`. And that's it. Note how our mainloop does not need to know what types exactly our sprites are.

We also make sure that all the logic for bullets is in the `Bullet` class, and all the logic for the cannon is in the `Cannon` class:

```
import pygame

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((4, 4))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(pos)
        self.travelled = pygame.Vector2(0, 0)
        direction = pygame.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) - self.pos
        if direction.length() > 0:
            self.direction = direction.normalize()
        else:
            self.kill()

    def update(self, dt):
        v = self.direction * dt / 5
        self.pos += v
        self.travelled += v
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if self.travelled.length() > 100:
            self.kill()

class Cannon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('darkred'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.timer = 200

    def update(self, dt):
        self.timer = max(self.timer - dt, 0)
        if self.timer == 0:
            self.timer = 200
            Bullet(self.rect.center, self.groups()[0])

def main():

    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 1
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                Cannon(e.pos, all_sprites)


        all_sprites.update(dt)

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Using a vector and simply adding the distance travelled each frame makes it easy to check for each `Bullet` if it already travelled 100 pixels. If true, simply calling `kill` will remove it.

Comment: Thank you, this is not exactly what I was looking for but it does help me out. Also I was able to accomplish my task using lists a while back but I was wondering what was wrong with my class.

Comment: Why does the sprite `__init__()` need the parameter as `*grps` and not just `grps`, and why are you passing it to the base-case `__init__()` too ?

Comment: @Kingsley a) because the parameter in the `Sprite` class itself is also a `*`-parameter. If you use `grps` instead of `*grps`, the `Sprite` class would recieve a nested tuple instead of a flat tuple. To be fair, it would still work because the `Sprite` class actually checks for this case and unpacks the tuple recursively b) it's a list of `Group`s the sprite is added on construction, see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)